# "How to format LocalDate with Custom Pattern" in Java

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I am new to JodaTime and learning it to my own. Actually what I want is to just format the `LocateDate` in my own format. My format is `"dd-mm-yyyy"`

I have method that calculates the difference with two dates:

```
private void sampleDaysDifference() {
    DateTime todayDate = getLocalTodayDate();
    DateTime dateAfterTwoDays = getDateAfterTwoDays();

    //get the days difference
    int differenceOfDates = Days.daysBetween(todayDate, dateAfterTwoDays).getDays();
    Log.e("logX","differenceOfDates: " + differenceOfDates);

}
```

To get the today date I am using:

```
private DateTime getLocalTodayDate() {
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    return fmt.parseDateTime(now.toString());//return the today date
}
```

and to get the date after two days:

```
private DateTime getDateAfterTwoDays() {
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    return fmt.parseDateTime(now.plusDays(2).toString());//return date after two days
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to format date using JodaTime, can somebody please tell me how to format a JodaTime `LocalDate`!

Actually my app is crashing with the stacktrace:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "16 January, 2019" is malformed at " January, 2019"
```

Comment: What is `DATE_FORMAT` you are using?

Comment: you mean, you format is `"dd-MM-yyyy"`

Comment: "dd-mm-yyyy" using this

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there but just the pattern is wrong that you specified, change `"dd-mm-yyyy"` to this `"dd-MM-yyyy"` [docs-for-patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

**Simple Example**

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));   //16-01-2019
```

From Joda `DateTimeFormatter` [joda-docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern(java.lang.String))

**The pattern syntax is mostly compatible with java.text.SimpleDateFormat**

Comment: are you using java-8? you should get it @JavaNerd

Comment: replacing `DATE_FORMAT` with `"dd-MM-yyyy"` you are using incorrect format  @JavaNerd

Comment: The link for the documentation of format patterns is wrong because it links to Oracle JDK but here the link to Joda-DateTimeFormatter is needed (the pattern syntax is slightly different!).

Comment: i check in joda also it's syas `The pattern syntax is mostly compatible with java.text.SimpleDateFormat` http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern(java.lang.String)

Comment: "mostly" is just similar to my word "slightly", no perfect agreement. In this case, it does not matter because both pattern types uses the same letter symbols for minutes and months, but it is generally better and safer to link to the Joda page here.